Kmedoids clustering assigns nodes to far away clusters?
I am currently trying to set up kmedoids clustering on a project I am working on in matlab. The basic approach works fine, but I have the additional constraint that there are obstacles on my map that are impassable and may separate parts of the map from each other. I solve this by using a custom distance function, which sets the distance to infinity if the straight line between the nodes passes through an obstacle. Otherwise I calculate the euclidean distance. My distance function looks like this:

function d2 = dist(Obs1,Obs)
global Red
d2 = [];
for i = 1:1:size(Obs,1)
lineseg = [Obs1(1,1) Obs1(1,2); Obs(i,1) Obs(i,2)];
[in,out] = intersect(Red,lineseg);
validPoints = ~isnan(in(:,1)) & ~isnan(in(:,2));
in = in(validPoints, :);
        plot(in(:,1),in(:,2),'r',out(:,1),out(:,2),'b')
        if isempty(in)
            dcal = pdist([Obs1;Obs(i,:)]);
        else
            dcal = Inf;
        end
        d2 = [d2;dcal];
    end
end


Where Red is a polyshape of my obstacles. Despite this, nodes that are very far away from each other sometimes get added to the same cluster, even if the straight line passes through the Red polyshape. I have no idea why this happened, I have tested everything I can think of. I appreciate any help.
One thing which I have noticed during my testing is, that all of the incorrectly assigned nodes are always assigned to the first cluster, maybe that's an indicator for where the problem lies, but I don't understand why.
Another thing that might be relevant is that my nodes are in 3D space, but I think I'm projecting them into 2D correctly for the intersection check.
I have added code that initializes the medoids so that at least one medoid starts in each separated area of the map, and I have verified by plotting, that this actually is the case and works correctly.
I have also tried setting the distance function to 'euclidean' instead of using my custom function. That works correctly and clusters nodes that are close together to the same cluster. It obviously ignores all obstacles in that case, which makes it useless for my use case.
I have enabled the Display=iter option on kmedoids, which returns
   rep      iter             sum
     1         1             Inf
     1         2             Inf
     1         3             Inf
     1         4             Inf
     1         5             Inf
     1         6             Inf
Best total sum of distances = Inf

That indicates to me that at least the intersections with the Red polyshape is detected correctly, it just doesn't seem to matter. I have also tried setting the distance to a high integer instead of Inf, which doesn't fix the problem either.
I have also printed out the cluster cost for different maps and plotted the clusters, where I realized that all incorrectly assigned nodes are added to the first cluster instead of the closest cluster, but I don't understand why that happens.
If you need any additional information, please let me know. Thanks for the help!

Can you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] we can test?
